# C++ gmock - what happens when passing null pointer to SaveArg

Tags: c++, pointers, googlemock, nullptr

I'm new to gmock and I'd like to understand the what happens when using SaveArg.

Here's what I found in gmock document:

`SaveArg<N>(pointer)` : Save the N-th (0-based) argument to *pointer.

does this mean:

1. make "pointer" point to the N-th argument, or
2. assign the value of the N-th argument to whatever pointed to by "pointer" ?

I'm thinking of the following situation:

```
class MockClass : public BaseClass {
 public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(somefunc,void(SomeType&));
};
```

then in my test function:

```
SomeType val; //make this live throughout the test
SomeType* pval = nullptr;

MockClass mymock;
EXPECT_CALL(mymock, somefunc(_)).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(pval));

//let's force a call
mymock.somefunc(val);

EXPECT_NE(nullptr, pval);
```

My point is:

if (1) is true, then what happens is: `pval = &val` --> the test will go through.

if (2) is true, then what happens is: `*pval = val` --> this will cause segmentation fault for pval is null pointer.

I have a situation similar to the one above, where I pass a nullptr to SaveArg and do not get segmentation fault, but the test is not passed either.

Would really appreciate if you guys could help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Question:

> SaveArg(pointer) : Save the N-th (0-based) argument to *pointer.
>
> does this mean:
>
> make "pointer" point to the N-th argument, or assign the value of the
>   N-th argument to whatever pointed to by "pointer" ?

Edit (correction by VladLosev) It's essentially the second, copy value of the N-th argument to whatever pointed by pointer.

So, regarding your observed behavior:

> I have a situation similar to the one above, where I pass a nullptr to
>   SaveArg and do not get segmentation fault, but the test is not passed
>   either.

This is due to implementation details of EXPECT_NE. Here's a short snippet from the [googletest FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/FAQ.md#why-does-google-test-support-expect_eqnull-ptr-and-assert_eqnull-ptr-but-not-expect_nenull-ptr-and-assert_nenull-ptr) on the matter:

> Due to some peculiarity of C++, it requires some non-trivial template
>   meta programming tricks to support using NULL as an argument of the
>   EXPECT_XX() and ASSERT_XX() macros. Therefore we only do it where it's
>   most needed (otherwise we make the implementation of Google Test
>   harder to maintain and more error-prone than necessary).

Short answer, when comparing to null with googletest, you should use ASSERT_EQ or EXPECT_EQ or some variation of *_TRUE. For more details, follow the link on the FAQ entry.

Comment: SaveArg is (2). The [implementation code](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/48ee8e98abc950abd8541e15550b18f8f6cfb3a9/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h#L172) makes that abundantly clear.

Comment: I wrote another piece of test code and can confirm that (2) is the actual behaviour.

Thanks a lot for helping me out @iheanyi VladLosev .